# Why does this give "one or more multiply defined symbols" error

Tags: c++, class, variables, header, symbols

I have two simple files. Ball.h and Ball.cpp.

When I compile my program, I get the error "one or more multiply defined symbols" for the variables int x and int y.

I understand that if I make those variables static, the error will go away, I do not understand why. I'm sorry if this is duplicate, but I could not understand the explanations that I have read elsewhere.

I have another class "Player" that also use int x and int y variables. Is that the cause of the issue?

Ball.cpp:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Ball.h"

const int BALL_SIZE = 20;
static int dx, dy;
static int x, y;

void Ball::Init(){
    x = 320;
    y = 240;
    dx = 1;
    dy = 1;
}

void Ball::Tick(){
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

void Ball::Render(SDL_Renderer* render){

}

void Ball::ReverseVelocity(){

}
```

Ball.h

```
#include <SDL.h>

class Ball{
    public:
        void Init();
        void Tick();
        void Render(SDL_Renderer* render);
        void ReverseVelocity();
};
```

Comment: Variable definitions have external linkage by default. If two or more of your translation units define `x` and `y`, every TU linking to these TUs will see multiple.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks! Are there any other solutions to this other than making the variables static or renaming them?

Comment: They are class members so declare them as private members, in the class header.

Comment: I think this raises the design question of *why* you are reusing x and y in multiple locations. Is there a reason why you cannot have these be class members? Presumably you would want to keep the information relating to the location of a ball and a player contained in the same class as the functionality that manipulates and renders those entities.

Comment: I just assumed that if they are in different classes they will not be seen as multiple.